# Get users between user ids

Tags: id, wp-user-query

How select users between 100 and 200 user ID's?
Or select users which ID less then 200?

```
$args = array (
   'query'     => array(
       array(
           'key'       => 'ID',
           'value'     => '200',
           'compare'   => '<=',
       ),
   ),
);

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

Comment: IDs are random number that you should not assume anything about, except for uniqueness. In theory you might not have any users between 100 and 200 but only above 10000

Comment: Why it's random? ID field in wp_users table have attribue Auto Increment, so it's not random number.

Comment: because that is the definition of the user ID. The fact that default implementation will have them with auto increment, do not mean that there may never be other implementations. If you will look around here you will find questions about how to change the user ID, or make it start in 10000

Comment: ... and obviously users can be deleted

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using the `include` with a range from 100 to 200:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( [ 'include' => range( 100,200 ) ] );
```

Comment: This way not good because in real I need select users from ID 2000 until 11000. And SQL putting all this ID's in string and mysql crashing. Need another way.

Comment: Why are you fetching so many each time (many thousands), why don't you use a paging instead (fetching like a 50-100 each time)?

Comment: I need this for script, that select users what I need and change something in their profile. I may use own `SELECT * from wp_users WHERE ID >= 2000 AND ID <= 11000` query, but I am interesting how do this with WP_User_Query

Comment: How are you updating each user? Is it run via cli or http request (timeout possible) ? It's possible to do this via filters, but I still wonder if you really need it ;-)

Comment: lol, the answer lack any elegance but it does literally answer the question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fetch a large range it is probably good to do this:

```
global $wpdb;

$users = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->users} WHERE ID > %d AND < %d",
        100,
        10000000
    )
);
```